# MySql: How to know if an entry is compressed or not

Tags: python, mysql

I'm working with python and mysql and I want to verify that a certain entry is compressed in the db. Ie:

```
cur = db.getCursor()
cur.execute('''select compressed_column from table where id=12345''')
res = cur.fetchall()
```

at this point I would like to verify that the entry is compressed (ie in order to *work* with the data you would have to use `select uncompress(compressed_column)..`). Ideas?

Comment: Are you mixing compressed and non-compressed data in the same column? Sounds like a bad idea to me...

Comment: I'm only testing not db-ing. I agree, it is a very bad idea

Answer (score 4):

`COMPRESS()` on MySQL uses zlib, therefore you can try the following to see if the string is compressed:

```
try:
  out = s.decode('zlib')
except zlib.error:
  out = s
```